# Delphi - Odd Hex Length in String after converting from Buffer to Hex?

Tags: delphi

**Situation:** *I'm hooking Send() & Recv() from ws2_32, Now I'm trying to convert the data that is contained at the Buffer with the function below. However when I do so, I see some packets are being displayed with 1 nibble (e.g. "CA FE BA BE DE AD CO D") and not 2 hex digits like we would normally see (e.g. "CA FE BA BE DE AD C0 DE").*

```
function ConvertDataToHex(Buffer: Pointer; Length: Word): string;

var
Iterator: Integer;
HexBuffer: string;
C: string;
Counter: Integer;
HexString: string;

begin
  HexBuffer := '';
  HexString := '';

for Iterator := 0 to Length - 1 do
  begin
    HexBuffer := HexBuffer +
      IntToHex(Ord(char(Pointer(Integer(Buffer) + Iterator)^)), 2);
  end;

for C in HexBuffer do
  begin
        Counter := Counter + 1;
        if not Odd(Counter) then
         begin
           HexString := C + ' ';
         end
        else
        begin
          HexString := C;
        end;
  end;
Result := HexString;
end;
```

Given the explanation above, do you see some anomaly in the code that could be causing some of the resulting strings to have have an odd length in the string?

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.Classes.BinToHex No need for the new wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns `HexString` which is either a single character, or a single character followed by a string. It certainly does not return what you expect it to return, or even claim that it returns.

The function should go like this:

```
function ConvertDataToHex(Buffer: Pointer; Len: Integer): string;
var
  i: Integer;
  P: PByte;
begin
  Result := '';
  P := Buffer;
  for i := 0 to Len-1 do begin
    Result := Result + IntToHex(P^, 2);
    if i<Len-1 then begin
      Result := Result + ' ';
    end;
    inc(P);
  end;
end;
```

As a simple demonstration, this code

```
var
  foo: Int64 = $0123456789abcdef;
....
Writeln(ConvertDataToHex(@foo, SizeOf(foo)));
```

results in this output:

```
EF CD AB 89 67 45 23 01
```

Comment: Flawless! and your solution is actually smaller! incredible :D Here's the new output: http://i.imgur.com/a79ZGMc.png - Deeply Appreciated!